# Inconsistencies in applying np.gradient function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gradient

Previously I had been calculating the gradient between a set of points by hand. I happened to see that in the numpy library there exists a np.gradient function.

Excitedly, I tried this on my local machine and it worked as below:

```
dataframe['Scrubber_Gradient_20m_mean'] = np.gradient(dataframe['ScrubberLevel'].rolling(center=False,window=2).mean())
```

This returned the rolling gradient values which is exactly what I was after. However, I have now moved some of my code to an AWS deployment on a Spyder Environment with the same numpy version as my local machine, and even though the code is the same, an error is suddenly thrown:

```
ValueError: Shape of array too small to calculate a numerical gradient, at least (edge_order + 1) elements are required.
```

[image: Scrub Gradient Error Message]

However, what doesn't make sense to me is that when I run the code **outside** of a function, and just in the console - the calculation works fine. The array is not 'too small', at least not from what I can see.

[image: No Error]

I can't understand the reason for this. Would anyone have any reasons for this potential inconsistent behaviour?

So far I have tried the following:

1. Check both Python Version / Numpy versions are the same on both AWS
   Server and Local Machine
2. Confirm both data sets are the same both inside function / outside function
3. Check Gradient Function Inside Function / Outside Function

My numpy version is: 1.15.1 on both my local machine and AWS server.

I have attached a snapshot of dummy data so that this can hopefully be replicated. Please use the ScrubberLevel column. [Link to Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lLot_zyqPEIwQH4WEvlw3aMd1Ho4zFkk)

This is the code I have used to run on my local machine:

```
df_condabri_central_T1['Scrubber_Gradient_hour_mean'] = np.gradient(df_condabri_central_T1['ScrubberLevel'].rolling(center=False,window=6).mean())
```

This is the code I have used to run on the AWS Spyder Environment within a function:

```
def feature_eng(dataframe):
#There are other features but for the sake of my problem I have restricted it to this variable
dataframe['ScrubberLevel'] = np.gradient(dataframe['ScrubberLevel'].rolling(center=False,window=2).mean())
return dataframe
```

Now when I run this **in the console** in AWS Spyder, there are no issues as seen below. 
[image: Screen when running code in AWS Spyder]

However, when I try and run this via my function, I get the following:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your post to include copy-pastable code using your dummy dataframe which generates both the success and the failure?  (Even better, slice your dummy dataframe down to a small object you could paste into your question.  Right now you're missing the M in [mcve].)

Comment: @DSM - Thank you so much for pointing this out! In the process of trying to recreate the issue so anyone else could replicate this, I happened to go through my function in significant detail and worked out I had an additional filter in place which seemed faulty and returned a frame length of 0. With this in mind, the error message thrown makes complete sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: Upvote because your question and comment helped me in solving my own problem.